# Application Cache manifest could not be fetched, because a redirection was attempted

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, mobile-safari

I'm writing an html application for the iPad, and my cache.manifest file lists all my assets.  I've verified that everything is cached by looking in the console of Google Chrome.

But when I go to Safari on the iPad, it says:

> Application Cache manifest could not be fetched, because a redirection
>   was attempted.

I'm even loading jQuery and jQuery mobile locally to make sure that loading them remotely is not causing this issue.

Comment: Using the web inspector on Safari on my PC, it says it's looking for /favicon.ico, which I don't have.

Comment: I've added a favicon.ico using <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />, but it's still giving me the error message.

Comment: Ah, it was because I wasn't using a relative link.  I was using a http:// link instead of ../

Comment: This will also happen if it's behind basic auth.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you link to the page with http://www.yourname.com/ instead of using a relative link, that will do it.

Comment: Hi, can you expand on what you mean by this? I'm having the same problem but I don't know what you mean